# Format and append textbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, textbox

I'm working on allowing formatting of messages on my site. Basically, my Bold, Italic, Underline, etc buttons, are going to append [b][/b], [i][/i], [u][/u], etc tags onto the text in my textbox.

I haven't even looked at formatting highlighted text, as I don't know how to detect which text in the textbox is highlighted...

Currently I'm working on the appending part...

```
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <div class="button style" id="btnBold"><b>B</b></div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtMailMessage" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="430" Height="100"></asp:TextBox></td>
</tr>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //
    // TEXT STYLE BUTTONS
    //
    $("#btnBold").click(function () {
        var textbox = $("#<%= txtMailMessage.ClientID %>");
        textbox.text(textbox.text + "[b][/b]");
    });
</script>
```

This seems to me like it'd work in theory...
What I was getting at with this code is preserving the current text in the textbox and then add on the tags.

Here's what I get if I try it while the textbox is empty:

```
function (a) {
    return p.access(this, function(a) {
        return a===b ? p.text(this) : this.empty().append((this[0] && this[0].ownerDocument || e).createTextNode(a))
    }, null, a, arguments.length)
}
```

If there is text already in the textbox, the click does nothing at all...

Can anyone help me with the append (mainly) and provide a bit of guidance on the formatting of selected text in the control?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing:

```
textbox.val(textbox.val() + "[b][/b]");
```

Did you try to put the tags around your text? If you want to format your text in your textbox, you should be doing this:

```
textbox.val("[b]" + textbox.val() + "[/b]");
```

If you want to put the tags around the selected text, or append if nothing is selected, you may create a javascript function to do that for you. Here's the code:

```
function addTagsToSelectedText(e) {
    var yourInputText = $("#yourtext");
    //Here you get the start of the selection
    var ss = yourInputText[0].selectionStart;
    //Here you get the end of the selection
    var se = yourInputText[0].selectionEnd;

    var text = yourInputText.val();
    //if there are no selections just append.
    if (ss == se)
        yourInputText.val(text + "[b][/b]");
    else
        yourInputText.val(text.substr(0, ss) + "[b]" + text.substr(ss, se) + "[/b]" + text.substring(se, text.length));
}
```

You'll need to use this function as a handler for the mousedown event. That's because when you click a button you lose the selection in the other elements you have. So you'll use it on mousedown, while the selection is still active:

```
<button onmousedown="addTagsToSelectedText(event)">click</button>
```

I hope it  helps.

Comment: Cool, thanks :) the work on selected text is a little arb though. It doesn't seem to be putting the end tag in... It's definitely something to do with the changes the substrings are making, but I'm not thinking clearly enough right now to figure it out

Comment: I mean it isn't putting the end tag in the right place... or the start tag if there are other tags in the text

Comment: Maybe the browser you are using. I tested this code on Chrome and it worked fine. Maybe on Internet Explorer it behaves in a different way. I suggest you to open the developer mode to debug the javascript and see what is being retrieved on the indexes ss and se.

Comment: Well, I'm using Chrome too, but will have a look at the values anyway